# How can you get the server time from Firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, server-side, firebase

I'm using angularjs with firebase and when I use

```
$scope.createdDate = new Date();
```

it uses the time on the client, however I want to use Firebase Servers current time as client-side time may vary. How can I go about this in angular?

Comment: is it this? https://www.firebase.com/docs/managing-presence.html#server-timestamps

Answer (score 19):

When you print `firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` it will give you this object `{.sv: "timestamp"}`

To reach the timestamp of firebase server **on client**, you first need to **write** the value to the server then **read** the value.

```
 firebase.database().ref('currentTime/').update({ time: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP })
    .then(function (data) {
      firebase.database().ref('currentTime/')
        .once('value')
        .then(function (data) {

          var t = data.val()['time'];
          console.log('server time: ', t);

        }, function serverTimeErr(err) {
          console.log('coulnd nt reach to the server time !');
        });
    }, function (err) {
      console.log ('set time error:', err)
    });
```

I think there must be an easier way to directly read the server timestamp from client.

**edit 1:** just found a better way uses 1 call to firebase

```
firebase.database().ref('/.info/serverTimeOffset')
  .once('value')
  .then(function stv(data) {
    console.log(data.val() + Date.now());
  }, function (err) {
    return err;
  });
```

Comment: hey, i used your methode but i keep getting a wrong date

Comment: how do u know if it is wrong? It is the time in the firebase server.

Comment: i got this timestamp = 1535916727292 which is equal to  07 April 50641. Is this normal?

Comment: my code after edit 1 looks pretty simple and it was working. Maybe firebase api changed

Comment: @FirasChebbah It's ms since epoch, not seconds.  Divide by 1000 if you want seconds.

Comment: I highly doubt the code in edit1 works.
Just to be clear if both the time on client and the server are accurate, the conversion works. But half the time the point of checking the server time is that we don't trust the device's clock. In those cases the solution doesn't help.

Comment: @hk1ll3r If you need to have atomic precision of course it doesn't help. In the end, we are bounded by the hardware we use. firebase uses websocket for communication. So it should be faster than HTTP. I think this solution is the best possible solution.

Comment: @canbax I'm not talking about atomic precision. For games some ppl change their device's clock to get around the time limits the games impose. Like if there is a daily ad they can watch only once a day, they set their clock to 24 hours ahead to see multiple ads per day. For those cases, you need the server time coming from the server without checking the device's clock. The first solution in this answer works for this use case.

Answer (score 15):

For firebase3, please use **firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP**

```
$scope.createdDate = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
```

[doc here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities)

Comment: Is there a way to get the server time without having to set it first ? (It's quite of weird to set it, then get it with a once, then try to take into account the delay is has taken to set it and then get it, and finally erase it).

Comment: I didn't get it well, dear. You can use firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP anytime without using .set method or others.

Comment: When trying to access the content of firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP from client-side, it throws the object {.sv: "timestamp"} . I believe it's a reference that is replaced automatically on the server side when seting or updating.

Comment: Verified in [this Docs Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ServerValue?hl=es#public-methods): ServerValue.TIMESTAMP is A placeholder value for auto-populating the current timestamp (time since the Unix epoch, in milliseconds) by the Firebase Database servers.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to Jonas Grumann for pointing out [this firebase doc](https://www.firebase.com/docs/managing-presence.html#server-timestamps) on how to add server time from firebase.

```
// Get created date from Firebase servers
var createdDate = new Firebase('https://somedomain.firebaseIO.com/post/createDate');
createdDate.set(Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
```

Answer (score -1):

2020: Now you can use `firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now()` to get the UNIX time from the server. It returns an object that looks like this:

```js
{
    seconds: NUM_OF_SECONDS,
    nanoseconds: NUM_OF_NANOSECONDS
}
```

From [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp) in the docs.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the `now()` function on a client does **not** perform a server request. Instead it will return the current client date. The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#static-now) states "Creates a new timestamp with the current date, with millisecond precision".

Comment: I just tested it by changing my computer clock. `firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now()` returns the client time.

Comment: yes ... so seems like there is no way doing it without cloud function ? :( @JohnnyOshika

Comment: @DaniilKunin Yeah, you'll need to call a server somewhere to get a trustable server time

Comment: makes sense!  @JohnnyOshika