# What is the best way to get Server Timestamp, using Firebase Cloud Firestore, Ionic Framework, Angular?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working in the project which truly based on clock time. It has a functionality to work same on desktop and mobile app (**Android/iOS**) using **Ionic Framework**.

If some of the user change the mobile time or system time, our complete app will get change the results.

So somewhere i found the some answer which shows that get the server time from web Server programming language.

But i am not using any  web framework language.

```
    triggerNextTicket(){
     Observable.interval(1000).map((x) => {
    let date = +new Date().getTime() ;
    if( (this.nextTicket.ticket_live_at.seconds * 1000) < date){
      this.ngOnInit();
    }
    if((this.ticketData.ticket_live_at.seconds * 1000) < date){
      this.ngOnInit();
    }
```

Actuaally, the main problem in this code is, if the Mobile system time changed by the user manually, then our **app shows the past data**.

```
let date = +new Date().getTime()
```

in any case my **date** variable will be fresh, if the user change their system time or in any case.

Thanks

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: If you do a search there are many services offering this functionality. Or you could create your own service to do this.

Comment: It can be possible to get the server timestamp from firebase @phuzi

Comment: Like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24202641/how-can-you-get-the-server-time-from-firebase

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you get the server time from Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24202641/how-can-you-get-the-server-time-from-firebase)

Comment: @phuzi: that question is for the Firebase Realtime Database, while this one is about Cloud Firestore. While both databases are part of Firebase, and both provide a way to set the server-side timestamp, the syntax is different.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here a simple way to tell Firestore to write the server-side timestamp to a document:

```
var ref = db.collection("54201787").doc("time");
ref.set({ timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() });
```

And here's how you read that value back into your client:

```
ref.onSnapshot(function(snapshot) {
  var timestamp = snapshot.data().timestamp;
  console.log(timestamp.toString());
})
```

In this last snippet the `timestamp` variable is a [`Date` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), so you can access all its other methods and properties too.

For a working sample of this code, see: https://jsbin.com/burimih/edit?html,js,console

Comment: Great, actually we have to fire an event when current clock time and event fire time match... Please imagine that cindition when user has wrong time in their devices.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means. My answer shows how to get the current server-time from Firestore. If you're having problems integrating that into your use-case, show the minimal code that reproduces the problem. I **highly** recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for that.

Comment: The code you now shared has nothing to do with reading the server timestamp from Firestore, which your title is all about. Did the problem after you posted it?

Comment: There is no reliable way to calculate the difference between a local time and server-side time in Firestore. That means you should either use two server-side timestamps, or two client-side timestamps. The former seems most likely, in which case you could for example write another server-side timestamp once the user starts waiting for the ticket. At that point you know what the "now" time is on the server, and when the next ticket is triggered, so you can calculate the difference.

Comment: You might also want to have a look at Firebase's older Realtime Database, which measures the offset between the client and the server time when the client connects. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#clock-skew

Answer (score 0):

You should use `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` while creating/updating a document as well as validate the same in security rules.

#### Example:

To set serverTime in a document

```
      db.collection("fooBar")
      .doc()
      .set({
        createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        createdBy: this.props.user.uid,
        foo: 'bar',
      })
      .then(() => console.log("Success"))
      .catch(console.error);
```

Security Rule

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if request.resource.data.createdBy == request.auth.uid && request.time == request.resource.data.createdAt
    }
  }
}
```

This way I can verify there are no client manipulated values in my database.

Also, notice how I validate user uid against `request.auth.uid`