# Defining Firebase Security Rules

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, angularfire2

I have below rules defined in my Rule set.

```
match /{document=**} {
         allow read: if request.time < resource.data.end ;
         allow read: if request.time > resource.data.end ;
         allow read: if resource.data.start > request.time;
}
```

For query :

```
this.afs.collection<events>('events', ref => ref.where('end' , '>' , firestore.Timestamp.now())).snapshotChanges();
```

I don't know why firebase throws permission error :

> ERROR FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

Where as for query :

```
this.afs.collection<events>('events', ref => ref.where('end' , '<' , firestore.Timestamp.now())).snapshotChanges();
```

Firebase doesn't throw any error and allows read.

Can anyone explain why am I getting error?

**UPDATE**

I am developing an App that displays list of events from database that span over two days from current time and has an option for registering for events. App also  displays events registered by user that are yet to start in the UPCOMING section and registered events that are completed in COMPLETED section. Events that had start time in past and start time in future(3+ days from now) are not shown in the App.

Earlier, I was using client's system time but the problem with that was user can change device time to past to see all the events in the past and user can change the time to future(3+ days from now) to see all upcoming events.

Later, I could prevent the time cheat by defining below rule for my DB.

```
match /{document=**} {
         allow read: if resource.data.start > request.time;
 }
```

This rule prevents time cheat but with this rule all alone I had issues fetching upcoming events (request.time < resource.data.end) and completed events (request.time > resource.data.end).
So, I included rules

```
match /{document=**} {
         allow read: if request.time < resource.data.end ;
         allow read: if request.time > resource.data.end ;
         allow read: if resource.data.start > request.time;
 }
```

And I was able to fetch completed events and left with permission error for upcoming events.

Comment: I've never seen multiple `read` clauses, so am not sure that is allowed. Can you try combining them with: `allow read: if request.time < resource.data.end || request.time > resource.data.end;`?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I tried combining them and still it throws an error.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Multiple uses of the same method is equivalent to a logical OR of each expression, which means if either condition is satisfied, access is allowed.

Comment: These rules don't make a whole lot of sense to me. It looks like they're saying "allow read access to every document except where `end` is the exactly same as the current time".  Could you describe what you're trying to accomplish here?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you said here:

> With these rules I am trying to display upcoming events (request.time
>   < resource.data.end) and completed events (request.time >
>   resource.data.end)

All I can say is that it doesn't seem like you need security rules at all.  Just allow read access to all the documents in the collection you want to query, and use them as you see fit.  Security rules are only needed if you want to restrict access to documents based on some criteria.  They aren't needed if you just want to do unbounded range filters.

Comment: In case if I remove such rules and allow read access to all the documents than user can fake/cheat by changing device time. Please look at this question of mine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60024385/how-to-check-for-time-sync-in-ionic-4-app-to-prevent-time-cheat-fake-by-user

Comment: Yeah, I answered that other question.

Comment: I think this kink will prove interesting for you : 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters

If your query returns any result for which the security rules don't allow the read then you will have the error message you mention.

The rule to remember : 
Query should always be MORE limiting than the security rules or you will get an error instead of your results.

Comment: I didn't give you that link.  That was someone else (check the name on the comment). It's not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish.  Please edit the question to explain in more detail what your queries are supposed to be doing, and how you would like the rules to allow or deny each specific query.  Your question now is just stating two queries that should work, but don't.

Comment: @oiawo thanks for the link but I did go through firebase docs before asking this question. And I cross checked my DB [ ;) DB has 4 docs ] and only one doc satisfies the criteria request.time < resource.data.end