# Firebase get wrong server timestamp, React Native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

When I use following code to set server timestamp in firestore it set proper time

```
firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()

//Set Val in firestore = {"seconds":1656487980,"nanoseconds":840000000}
//June 29, 2022 7:33:00 AM
```

At the same time I use following code to get current timestamp value in device it get wrong timestamp

```
Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()); // {"seconds":1656491580,"nanoseconds":840000000} //June 29, 2022 8:33:00 AM
Timestamp.now(); // {"seconds":1656491580,"nanoseconds":840000000} //June 29, 2022 8:33:00 AM

//Also Unix timestamp get locally code get wrong time
(new Date()).getTime(); //1656491580000 //June 29, 2022 8:33:00 AM
```

**It happens after change my device time to manually +1 hour in mobile setting**

> How can i get correct timestamp value after change device time?

Comment: As per my understanding of your issue, can you go through this article https://medium.com/firebase-developers/the-secrets-of-firestore-fieldvalue-servertimestamp-revealed-29dd7a38a82b which says "When you call FieldValue.serverTimestamp(), you’ll get back a FieldValue type object that stands in for the current moment in time The actual value of this FieldValue token doesn’t actually contain any time data in it. You can’t get time values out of it, and you can’t do time math with it. It is just a token.

Comment: When you provide the token as the value for a field when writing a document, Firestore writes a Timestamp type value to the field with Google’s sense of the current time, at the time the write hit the server. When you print firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP it will give you this object {.sv: "timestamp"}
To reach the timestamp of firebase server on the client, you first need to write the value to the server then read the value.

Comment: Go through the article above and this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46401234/15803365) I think you have to first attach a listener to the document, then write a createdAt field in that document with FieldValue.serverTimestamp(), The listener fires, and you get the existing value of the timestamp.
The listener fires again, and you observe null for the createdAt field.
The listener fires yet again, and you observe an actual timestamp value. I think the document needs to get synchronized with the server, to get new timestamp value determined by Firestore.

Comment: Hi @BhaumikSurani Did the suggestion help you? Were you able to work out your issue?

Comment: Yes but in my case i use own api call bcz it require some kind of validation.